# How to recursively match strings balanced with multi-character delimiters?

Tags: regex, perl, recursion

How can I recursively match a string balanced with **multi-character** delimiters?

Consider a LaTeX inline quotation such that 2 doubleticks (``` `` ```) mark up where the quote begins, and 2 apostrophes (`\x27\x27`) where it ends.

The following code gives me ``` ``five'' ```.  I want to capture ``` two ``three `four' ``five'' three four'' six ```

```
my $str = q|one ``two ``three `four' ``five'' three four'' six'' seven|;

if ( $str =~ /
              (
              ``
                (?:
                     [^`']
                       |
                     (?1)
                )*
              ''
              )
            /x
   )
   {
     print "$1\n";
   }
```

I guess it has to do with how to negate, not a character class (`` [^`'] ``, but multi-character strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(?:(?!PAT)(?s:.))*` is to `PAT` as `[^CHAR]*` is to `CHAR`, so

```
(?:(?!``|'')(?s:.))*
```

matches any character that isn't the start of those two sequences. However, I think lookaheads are little expensive, so I believe

```
(?: [^`']+ | `(?!`) | '(?!') )*
```

would be cheaper. We get the following:

```
/
   (
      ``
         (
            (?: [^`']+ | `(?!`) | '(?!') )*
            (?:
               (?-2)
               (?: [^`']+ | `(?!`) | '(?!') )*
            )*
         )
      ''
   )
/x
```

We can simplify for a small performance drop.

```
/
   (
      ``
         (
            (?: [^`']+
            |   `(?!`)
            |   '(?!')
            |   (?-2)
            )*
         )
      ''
   )
/x
```

In both snippets, The text you want to capture is in `$2`.

Comment: Nice. The cheaper approach, however, would not work with, say, `<div>` and `</div>`. In this case, we would still need to fall back to the expensive one, right?

Comment: No, it will also work for `<div>` and `</div>`. Method 1: `(?:(?!</?div>).)*` Method 2: `( [^<]+ | <(?!/?div>) )*`

Comment: Added a simpler solution.

Comment: Updated my answer so it doesn't include the delimiters in the desired text.